# Permission denied (public key) for ubuntu user but not for root on AWS EC2 instance

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, public-key-encryption

Yesterday I was able to use my key pair to log into my EC2 instance, but this morning it tells me "Permission denied (public key)".

I am on an ubuntu AMI, I checked that I was trying the correct user name. However what is interesting is that when I try to ssh in using 'root', it connects and authenticates successfully, but tells me to use 'ubuntu' instead and terminates the connection.

How can the public key work for root, but not for the 'ubuntu' user?

Is there perhaps something wrong with the permissions for user 'ubuntu' on the EC2 instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had changed the permissions on the ubuntu user's home directory.

Answer (score 0):

Public key/private key pair added in .ssh directory of every user. Check where you hace added this key. in ssh directory of root user or ssh directory of ubuntu user. ssh directory is different for all users.

You can find this directory as /home/ubuntu/.ssh