# EC2 - Permission denied(public key) while the same key works for other instance and other user on the instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Everything worked great till yesterday. Today I am unable to `ssh` to my `ec2` instance.

The settings are saved in `.ssh/config`.

The error I get, when using `test` username:

> .us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey).

I went ahead and double checked the permission on the `.pem` file:

```
-r--------
```

I have another `ec2` running with the same `.pem` so I connected to it. No problem, login done.

I then tried to `ssh` into the problematic `ec2` with `ubuntu` user and same `.pem` file. It worked I was able to login.

I then switched users and the `test` user exists.

I am not sure about what the issue might be.

Exited the `ssh` session and tried connection again using the `test` user and got the same error.

I found an answer here:

[Same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26624677/permission-denied-public-key-for-ubuntu-user-but-not-for-root-on-aws-ec2-insta)

But the answer is not very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be permission issue on the .ssh directory of the test user on the remote box

- Connect the same way with ubuntu user.
- Compare **the permissions on ssh directory** of test user and all its content (authorized keys, known host, config) with the one of ubuntu user.
- Check content of **authorized_keys** file in test ssh directory and make sure it **matches the public key** of the private key you are connecting with.
- You can use ssh -vvv while connecting, to check if it is using the right key while connecting.
- **Final resort:** tail the ssh logs while you are trying to connect with test user.

Comment: The third point was where the problem was, the `authorized_keys` file didn't have the `.pem` key. I copied the entries from `ubuntu` user into the `authorized_keys` file and now I can `ssh`. If you wouldn't mind please expand the steps or I will in a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Abraam's answer is absolutely correct.

I am detailing the steps I followed to check and change the `authorized_keys` in remote i.e. the `EC2` instance.

ssh using the `ubuntu` user:

```
ssh -i "~/path/to/key-pair.pem" ubuntu@ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xx.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

see the entries in ubuntu `authorized_keys`:

```
cat /home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

change user to `test`

```
su test
```

see the entries in test `authorized_keys`:

```
cat /home/test/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

if there is a difference and the key-pair is not present

```
# copy the key entry from the ubuntu authorized_keys
nano /home/test/.ssh/authorized_keys
# new line, paste the copied authorized_key
```

Save and close the file.

`ssh` should work now.